# Git pull from perl

Tags: git, perl

I'm attempting to automate code backups into git, with little success.  In this case I'm attempting it in perl.  My current issue is that git expects to be in the proper directory when run. (pay attention to the third line.) I'm receiving the error: **fatal: Invalid refspec 'dest=c:\data\git\aperio\Scratch\src\rich'**
Is there a way to define my directory as an arg?  Or failing that running in an environment pointed to the directory?

**Note:** I recognize this will be a problem for most git commands, not just the pull.

```
    ...
    @file=("deploy*.bat","deploy.ini","product.lic");
    system("$gitexe checkout integrate");
    system("$gitexe pull url=https://github.com/Aperio/aperio/Scratch/src/rich dest=c:\\data\\git\\aperio\\Scratch\\src\\rich");
    exit if ($testing);
    my $message="Changed: ";
    foreach $file (@file) {
        my ($src,$git,$timestamp,$sb,$message);
        my @files = glob($file);
        foreach my $f (@files) {
            $git=$gitdir."\\rich\\".$f;
            say $git;
            # Update git if needed
            if ((stat($git))[9] < (stat($f))[9]) { 
                $message.="$f, ";
                system("robocopy.exe . $gitdir /R:3 /Z /XO $f"); # Copy file to git folder
                system("$gitexe add $gitdir\\rich\\$f");
            }
        }
    }
    system("$gitexe commit -m $message");
    system("$gitexe status");
    system("$gitexe push origin ");
```

Comment: What you're implementing can probably be better done with [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) and one `git add .` call.

Comment: Is the problem building the command in the first place (a git or shell problem), or getting the command to execute from Perl (a Perl issue)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can set [the `GIT_DIR` environment variable or the `--git-dir` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) to tell git what `.git` directory to use.

However, you're better off using something like [Git.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Git).

```
use Git;

my $repo = Git->repository(Directory => '/srv/git/cogito.git');
$repo->command("commit", "-m", $message);
```

This avoids numerous problems like shell escaping, error handling, capturing output, and forgetting to set `--git-dir`.